# Serving Vector Tiles to TerriaJS (TerriaMap)?

Tags: vector, terriajs

Does Terriajs support  mapbox vector tiles format?

I've created vector tiles with tippecanoe and am serving them with tileserver-gl I have not been able to add them to TerriaJS.

I do not see a catalog item for vector tiles.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs/blob/master/doc/connecting-to-data/catalog-items.md
https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs/blob/master/doc/customizing/initialization-files.md

The MapBox Catalog Item is only for their Raster Tiles. It does not look like it's supported.